# Enumeration of a set

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

What do this statement mean: For any given $k\in \left[a,b\right]$, let $\left( x_n \right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be an enumeration of the set $\left\{c_jy_k^i:i,j\ge 1, \right\}$ where $c_j$ is a real number for all $j\ge 1$?

Answer (score 1):

Some context is missing: what are the $y_j^i$?
If they form a countable set, then you can enumerate it, i.e. rewrite your set $\{x_n : n\in\mathbb N^*\}$ where all the $x_n$ are distinct.

This would imply that there are a lot of $i,j,j'$ such that $y_j^i=y_{j'}^i$, otherwise your set is not countable.

Comment: Sorry I edited the post

Comment: it's worst than before...

Comment: may be, but this is what I want

Comment: I mean you don't define what the $y_k^i$ are, and also $k$ is not defined. Either it's not relevant and remove it, or define it...

Comment: I mentioned that $k\in \left[a,b\right]$ and $i$ is the power of $y_k$

Answer (score 1):

It means that the map $\mathbb N\to \{\,y_j^i:i\ge 1,j\in[a,b]\,\}$ that maps $n\mapsto x_n$ is a bijection.

Comment: Sorry I edited the post

Answer (score 0):

It means that for each positive integer $n$, $x_n$ is an element of your set, and that for each element $p$ of your set, there's just one positive integer $n$ such that $x_n = p$.

It's an "enumeration" because such a correspondence implicitly places an order on the elements of your set: $x_1$ is the "first", $x_2$ is the second, and so on, so you have, by writing down this correspondence, "numbered" the elements of the set.

It appears that the set on the right is NOT denumerable (if I'm interpreting the notation correctly); my guess is therefore that this "let $\{x_n\}$ be an enumeration" probably occurs in the middle of a proof by contradiction.

[OK, now that you've edited the statement, that last paragraph no longer makes sense.]

Comment: Sorry I edited the post

Comment: That's OK. Aside from the last paragraph, my answer still applies. You've got three correct answers here...do you want to accept one?